# How can I reshape the bar graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to resize the graph:

```
act_df %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Id, y = hours, fill = hour_type)) +
geom_col(position = "fill") +
coord_flip()
```

because it looks like this:
[image]

1. An Id just expresses a person so it is not numeric. I want the vertical gaps between bars are same.
2. The overall size should be larger than this.(especially horizontally)

How should I change this chart to make it more readable?

Comment: try turning `Id` into a factor.

Comment: As a factor? Could you explain it more?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(act_df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an example of making the `Id` column a factor on some simulated IDs:

```r
library(tidyverse)

act_df <- tibble(
  Id = sample (10000:99999, 20),
  a = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
  c = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
  d = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Id, names_to = "hour_type", values_to = "hours")

act_df %>%
  mutate(Id = as_factor(Id)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Id, x = hours, fill = hour_type)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Making it a factor, rather than an integer, tells R to 'ignore' the distance between each ID (i.e. stop treating it as a continuous variable) and plot each one labelled side by side.

For future reference - in this question and your other related question - it helps a lot to give some sample data using `dput` to be sure we're answering the right question. Simulating data (as I've done above) is one way of recreating a problem without using sensitive/restricted data.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: ThanksI came to realize my question is not appropriate thanks to people who answered for my questions so I am studying dput.

Comment: Don't worry! Getting used to stackoverflow and getting the most out of questions takes a bit of practice. If it helps, I tend to use `datapasta::tribble_paste()` for putting data samples in places - looks a lot nicer! See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html for some handy functions. Other helpful guidance at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use `width =` argument. Here is an example:

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = am)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 0.05) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

changing `width` in `geom_col`:

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = am)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 1.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: act_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Id, y = hours, fill = hour_type)) +
    geom_col(position = "fill", width = 2) +
    coord_flip()

Comment: I tried above but still not readable. I think the overall size of the graph should be enlarged.